# Округление в C#

Tags: c#, округление

Есть число типа double

Нужно округлить данное число до N знаков после запятой используя округления:
 математическое (обычное школьное), банкирское (к ближайшемо чётному), обрезание (просто обрезать до N знаков после запятой)

Как это сделать средствами языка C# ?

Пример:

value = 0.428509, N = 3

мат. :0.429

банк. :0.428

обрез. :0.428

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, округление не до целого числа не имеет смысла для чисел типа `double`, т. к. числа наподобие `0.1` вовсе не могут быть представлены точно в виде двоичных дробей.

Поэтому вычисления имеют смысл лишь для типа данных `decimal`, который как раз представляют собой десятичные дроби.

Заметьте, что разные типы округления дают разные результаты только в случае, когда исходное число заканчивается на 5, и округление происходит на один разряд. В противном случае округление всегда идёт вниз для последней цифры меньше 5, или вверх для больше 5. В вашем примере последняя цифра — не 5, и правильный результат для банковского округления — тоже `0.429m`. Результат `0.428m` был бы для числа `0.4285m`. (`m` в конце обозначает константу типа `decimal`)

Для банковского округления есть стандартная функция:

```
decimal value = 0.428509m;
int N = 3;
decimal bankers = decimal.Round(value, N, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

Если вы подразумеваете под обычным школьным округлением округление, которое для чисел заканчивающихся на 5 округляет вверх, используйте

```
 decimal standard = decimal.Round(value, N, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Для truncate (обрезания) поддержки в стандартной библиотеке нет, и вам нужно сначала вычислить 10m в степени N (умножением в цикле), умножить `value` на получившееся число, выполнить `decimal.Truncate`, а затем поделить назад. Код, надеюсь, напишете сами?

Answer (score 4):

Функция [Math.Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx#Round1_Example) не поддерживает указанный вами режим, поэтому напишите свой кастомный метод:

```
public static double Truncate(double value, int precision)
{
    return Math.Truncate(value * Math.Pow(10, precision)) / Math.Pow(10, precision);
}
```

Взято отсюда: [Truncate number of digit of double value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392244/5752652) - там же можете вдохновиться примером с переводом в строку и обрезкой ненужной части, если не очень хочется использовать функцию возведения в степень.

Также, стоит задуматься, почему вы используете такую странную и редкую форму округления, которой даже нет в стандартной библиотеке. Возможно, вам всё же подойдёт вариант из стандартных [AwayFromZero или ToEven](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx).